# In John 4:51 why a son (παῖς) and not a son (υἱός)?

Tags: greek, john, word-study

[υἱός](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G5207&t=KJV) is most common way to call a child a son. In John, this word is used [57 times](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G5207&t=KJV&bn=43#lexResults). However, there is one instance where [παῖς](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G3816&t=KJV) is used:

> As he was going down, his servants met him and told him that his son was recovering.
>   (John 4:51) [ESV]
>
> > ἤδη δὲ αὐτοῦ καταβαίνοντος οἱ δοῦλοι αὐτοῦ ὑπήντησαν αὐτῷ λέγοντες ὅτι ὁ παῖς αὐτοῦ ζῇ

The official, Jesus and John always call the child a υἱός:

> So he came again to Cana in Galilee, where he had made the water wine. And at Capernaum there was an official whose son was ill. When this man heard that Jesus had come from Judea to Galilee, he went to him and asked him to come down and heal his son, for he was at the point of death. (4:46-47)
>
> > ἦλθεν οὖν πάλιν εἰς τὴν Κανὰ τῆς Γαλιλαίας ὅπου ἐποίησεν τὸ ὕδωρ οἶνον καὶ ἦν τις βασιλικὸς οὗ ὁ υἱὸς ἠσθένει ἐν Καφαρναούμ οὗτος ἀκούσας ὅτι Ἰησοῦς ἥκει ἐκ τῆς Ἰουδαίας εἰς τὴν Γαλιλαίαν ἀπῆλθεν πρὸς αὐτὸν καὶ ἠρώτα ἵνα καταβῇ καὶ ἰάσηται αὐτοῦ τὸν υἱόν ἤμελλεν γὰρ ἀποθνῄσκειν
>
> Jesus said to him, “Go; your son will live.” The man believed the word that Jesus spoke to him and went on his way. (4:50)
>
> > λέγει αὐτῷ ὁ Ἰησοῦς πορεύου ὁ υἱός σου ζῇ ἐπίστευσεν ὁ ἄνθρωπος τῷ λόγῳ ὃν εἶπεν αὐτῷ ὁ Ἰησοῦς καὶ ἐπορεύετο
>
> The father knew that was the hour when Jesus had said to him, “Your son will live.” And he himself believed, and all his household. (4:53)
>
> > ἔγνω οὖν ὁ πατὴρ ὅτι ἐν ἐκείνῃ τῇ ὥρᾳ ἐν ᾗ εἶπεν αὐτῷ ὁ Ἰησοῦς ὁ υἱός σου ζῇ καὶ ἐπίστευσεν αὐτὸς καὶ ἡ οἰκία αὐτοῦ ὅλη

Why do the servants tell the man his παῖς is better not his υἱός, as the man calls his son?

Comment: I like to think that υἱός corresponds well to the English word "son" while παῖς corresponds more to the English word "boy" in that it is used to refer to one's son or, depending on context, to one's servant, possibly disrespectfully.

Comment: *Paidion* appears a couple of verses earlier (5:49), as well as in 16:21. *Paidarion* appears in 6:9. *Paidia* appears twice in 1 John 2 (verses 13 and 18).

Comment: It's surely cognate with Latin's *puer* meaning boy-child. As in, Puer natus est nobis, et filius datus est nobis: "Unto us a child is born: unto us a son is given."

Answer (score 1):

The words for the child are characteristic: the father uses paidion, the term of endearment; Jesus and the Evangelist use uios, the term of dignity; the servants the more familiar pais. All from E.S.V:

"pais" can be translated "servant" as in Luke 1:54 "his servant Israel",

or Luke 7:7 "let my servant be healed".

But "pais" is also translated "boy" Luke 2:43 "the boy stayed behind",

or Luke 8:51 "child" in "the father and mother of the child".

What determines the difference being who is talking and the way they are talking. In Luke 1:54 Mary is talking of Israel in the realm of past national events and "pais" becomes "servant". "He has helped his servant Israel".

"huios" is used in formal announcements as in:

John 1:34 "this is the Son [huios] of God".

John 1:45 "Jesus of Nazareth, the son [huion] of Joseph".

John 1 51 "you will see heaven opened, and the angels of God ascending and descending on the Son [huion] of God".

In John 4:51 when the servants speak they are not making a formal announcement so they don't use "huion".

They are not talking about another servant which could be "pais".

They are talking about their master's son "pais" but as "boy" or "child".

Comment: I am intrigued by your testimony on your profile. There are similarities to my own. (Spiritual experience as an infant and I am now in my seventies.) I would be interested in your efforts to document your notes. I have written some books over the past ten years, myself. They are on my website whose address is on my profile, as is my email address. I am in the UK. Kind Regards, _Nigel._